# Strongly typed TempData in Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

With Web Forms, I could create a wrapper for a strongly typed Session:

```
public class MySession
{
    public static MySession Current
    {
        get
        {
            MySession session = (MySession)HttpContext.Current.Session["__MySession__"];

            if (session == null)
            {
                session = new MySession();
                HttpContext.Current.Session["__MySession__"] = session;
            }

            return session;
        }
    }

    public string TestString { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to do the same thing for TempData in Core:

```
public class MySession
{
    public static MySession Current
    {
        get
        {
            var _sessionId = "_MyTempData_";

            var httpContext = new HttpContextAccessor().HttpContext;
            var tempDataFactory = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITempDataDictionaryFactory>();
            var tempData = tempDataFactory.GetTempData(httpContext);

            var val = tempData.Peek(_sessionId) as string;

            MySession mySession;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val))
            {
                mySession = new();
                tempData[_sessionId] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mySession);
                tempData.Save();
            }
            else
                mySession = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MySession>(val);

            return mySession;
        }
    }

    public string TestString { get; set; }

}
```

But my TestString value is alway null:

```
MySession.Current.TestString = "Test";
var x = MySession.Current.TestString //always null
```

Is it because I was able to store the actual MySession object, so it was referenced, or something?

Comment: `new HttpContextAccessor()` you are not supposed to do this. A new instance of `HttpContextAccessor()` does not give you the same httpContext which is used by the controllers. Also every call to this Current property will create a new HttpContextAccessor which will result in everything new. Even the tempdata dictionary. That's why you are not getting the value back even after you set it first

Answer (score 0):

Please note, in .net core it is no good practice to use HttpContext class to store data state.

There are designated classes that do the operations, cleaner and with more efficiency. In your case, in order to store session state you can use the [Isession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.isession?view=aspnetcore-6.0) interface.

It implements the traditional `Get`, `Set` methods for string and int (int32, int16).

The [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0) I attached should cover the use cases and give you a hint on how to use this.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a non-static class and separating the data from the logic?

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Test
{
    // Add to Startup.cs
    // services.AddScoped<SessionService>();

    public class SessionService
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private readonly ITempDataDictionaryFactory _tempDataDictionaryFactory;
        private readonly string _sessionId = "_MyTempData_";
        
        public SessionService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, ITempDataDictionaryFactory tempDataDictionaryFactory)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _tempDataDictionaryFactory = tempDataDictionaryFactory;
        }

        public SessionData Current
        {
            get
            {
                var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
                var tempData = _tempDataDictionaryFactory.GetTempData(httpContext);

                var val = tempData.Peek(_sessionId) as string;

                SessionData mySession;
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val))
                {
                    mySession = new();
                    tempData[_sessionId] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mySession);
                    tempData.Save();
                }
                else
                    mySession = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SessionData>(val);

                return mySession;
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Separate class for the data,

```
namespace Test
{
     public class SessionData
     {
        public string TestString { get; set; }
     }
}
```

Usage in a ASP.NET Core webpage:

```
namespace Test
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly SessionService _sessionService;
        private SessionData SessionData => _sessionService.Current;

        public HomeController(SessionService sessionService)
        {
            _sessionService = sessionService;
        }
        
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var hi = SessionData.TestString;
            
            return View(hi);
        }
    }
}
```